# How to call object of a function in one class in another class?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

I have a function in class `ADialog`which has a user input `x11` that I want to call in a function in class `BDoc`. How to do it?

```
.h file
#ifndef A_DIALOG_H
#define A_DIALOG_H

class ADialog : public wxDialog
{
public:
      ADialog(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, int click);
      wxTextCtrl *d_x1;
      void setAData();  
};
#endif
```

part of .cpp file

```
void ADialog::setAData()
{
    double x11; 
    d_x1->GetValue().ToDouble(&x11);    
}
```

part of .cpp file

```
void BDoc::ATCut()
{
    //(get the value of x11 that user inputs in this part)
}
```

Comment: I don't see any methods in `ADialog`.

Comment: isn't setAData() a member function?

Comment: It's not declared as such in the class declaration. I have no idea if it's `public` or `private`. Is it `static` or not? Can you post the full class.

Comment: oh okay sorry, its public, I'll edit that

Comment: Because it's not `static`, you need an instance of `ADialog` in `BDoc` to get the result from that method.

Answer (score 0):

Include `ADialog` class header in your caller class `BDoc`, then call `SetAData()`

```
ADialog obj;
obj.SetAData();
```

you can modify `SetAData()` to return `x11` if you want.

Comment: I did that but then x11 is not accessed

Comment: and I can't change the type, it is void. I mean changing the type would mean changing a lot more things so I wanted to know if there was any other way round

Comment: @Leo001 how about having `x11` as a member variable and access it via a public interface ?

Comment: @Leo001 can you get `x11` in `BDoc` directly via `d_x1` ?

Comment: thanks a lot I just found a way round by declaring a pointer in another class and then calling it in ADialog::setAData aswxGetApp().getPattern()->xc1=x11

Answer (score -1):

Make class ADialog friend of class BDoc. So you can easily access class ADialog function in class BDoc.

Comment: @Leo001 So a missing `friend` relationship isn't the culprit. Forget about this _"answer"_.